# Help with batch file to copy files in subdir to within dir

Tags: batch-file, dos

Can anyone provide me with a dos batch loop thru sub directories to copy a file to within the same directory to another file using the sub directory name within the same directory.

Example:

Movies =>
       Aladdin =>
                wd_tv.jpg

Would like to copy wd_tv.jpg within same dir to "directoryname"_sheet.jpg
So after the batch has run the directory would be:

Moves =>
      Aladdin =>
                wd_tv.jpg,
                Aladdin_sheet.jpg

With Aladdin_sheet.jpg being the wd_tv.jpg copied and renamed.
Hope its possible 
Thks In Advance.

Comment: test.jpg is an uncommon name for a subdir

Comment: oops i meant test.jpg is the files in a subdir

Comment: Please edit your question, including dir and file names.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this batchfile to the movies direcory and execute it there.

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*) do call :rendir %%a

echo finished
pause
goto :eof

:rendir
pushd %1
echo renaming *.jpg to %1_sheet.jpg
ren *.jpg %1_sheet.jpg
popd

goto :eof

:eof
```